# No row with the given identifier exists : Hibernate Merge

Tags: hibernate, merge

I am getting No row with the given identifier exists exception when trying to do `session.merge(entity)` for the parent. Basically, I am having @OnetoMany within the same table. Below are the steps I followed.

1. Loaded the parent.
2. Deleted the child using `session.delete(entity)` and also removed it from parent entity using iterator remove.
3. Made some update to parent entity which is already loaded.
4. Trying to merge parent entity using session.merge(entity). At this line, I am getting **No row with the given identifier exists** exception.
   I also tried to make an update in the parent before deleting child but same error. Below is my entity.

```html
    public class Account{  
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "idgen")  
    protected Long id;  

    @Column(name = "SOME_ID")  
    private String someId;  

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ACCT")  
    @ManyToOne  
    private Account parentAccount;  

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = 
    "parentAccount")  
    private Set<Account> sleeves;  
    }
```